# Unable to Run swim traffic example through Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: linux, java, traffic

I try to run an example of Swim OS Traffic traffic on my computer but I am getting an issue. I downloaded and followed [the instructions at this link](https://github.com/swimos/traffic).

Installed version on my Windows 10 64-bit Computer:

```
JDK v9
Node Js v8.9.3
npm 6.9.0
Enable Windows Subsystem for Linux feature
Ubuntu 18.04 Windows App from store
```

But after all those steps when I am trying to run `run.sh`, I am getting below error:

[image]

Comment: Within Ubuntu WSL, make sure the environment understands the location of Java.  Update your question to provide that indication.

Comment: Sorry you are facing this issue. But regarding the screenshots, they are very hard too read. Is it possible for you to just copy and paste sample error message text and add it to the question itself?